# Is there a Python equivalent of the shell command `cp -r <directory> <existing_directory>`?

Tags: python, shell, command-line

In bash, if I have a directory `foo` but no directory `bar`, then the command

> cp -r foo bar

will create the directory `bar` and this directory will contain the contents of `foo`.
The Python equivalent of this is `shutil.copytree("foo", "bar")`.

However, if I have a directory `foo` and also a directory `bar`, then the command

> cp -r foo bar

will create a new directory `foo` underneath `bar` with all the contents of `foo` in it.

Is there a Python equivalent of this, without

> a) invoking the actual command using `os.system`  or
>
> b) manually extracting the base name of the directory `foo`, appending it to bar using `os.path.join`, and then running `copytree`

That is, does Python have a concept of copying **into** directories?

Update: Both of the "duplicate" questions have solutions that do not copy "into" directories but rather "over" directories. The use of such solutions would require manual extraction of the base name of directory `foo`, appending it to `bar` and then using `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree`. I am explicitly looking for a solution that does not require this.

If `bar` already exists, `cp -r foo bar` will create a new `foo` inside `bar` with all contents of `foo`. On the other hand `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree` will put everything in `foo` inside `bar` without creating a new `foo`.

Comment: The documentation for `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree` suggests that I would need to use os.path.join.

Comment: @dave,  please see my clarifying update.

Comment: your update doesn't seem invalid. at the end of the day, if foo is a directory right under the current working directory, then cp knows how to expand it because it can get a current working directory. ``os.path.join`` is not necessary if your cp is relative to ur os.getcwd().

Comment: It is not the expansion of `foo` that is interesting, it is the fact that `cp` realizes that `bar` exists, and creates a new directory under it.

Comment: Well mind to tell me why shutil.copy doesn't work for you? what are your constraints that makes you want to look for a new module? This is a strange requirement to be honest. Are you working on a non-conventional, cloud-based filesystem?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I was simply trying to write it in less lines of code. =P

Comment: no you can't. Python is a language. CPython is an implementation. The language only knows about grammar. The implementation adds modules. You as developer should take care these things explicitly. It's for safety purpose :p